# R: Writing data frame into excel with large number of rows

Tags: r, excel

I have a data frame (panel form) in R with 194498 rows and 7 columns. I want to write it to an Excel file (.xlsx) using function `res <- write.xlsx(df, output)` but R goes in  the coma (keeps showing stop sign on the top left of console) without making any change in the targeted file(output). Finally shows following:
`Error in .jcheck(silent = FALSE) : 
  Java Exception <no description because toString() failed>.jcall(row[[ir]], "Lorg/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Cell;", "createCell", as.integer(colIndex[ic] - 1))<S4 object of class "jobjRef">` 
I have loaded readxl and xlsx packages. Please suggest to fix it. Thanks.

Comment: You should try package `XLConnect

Comment: Tried and gives error. Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable)  : 
  unable to find an inherited method for function ‘writeWorksheet’ for signature ‘"tbl_df", "character", "numeric"

Comment: Change the class of your "tbl_df" to a true data.frame. this is probably dplyr biting you.

Comment: Yes it has been biting me a lot lately

Answer (score 4):

Install and load package named 'WriteXLS' and try writing out your R object using function WriteXLS(). Make sure your R object is written in quotes like the one below "data".

```
 # Store your data with 194498 rows and 7 columns in a data frame named   'data'

 # Install package named WriteXLS
 install.packages("WriteXLS")

 # Loading package
 library(WriteXLS)

 # Writing out R object 'data' in an Excel file created namely data.xlsx 
 WriteXLS("data",ExcelFileName="data.xlsx",row.names=F,col.names=T)
```

Hope this helped.

Answer (score 2):

This does not answer your question, but might be a solution to your problem.

Could save the file as a CSV instead like so:

```
write.csv(df , "df.csv")
```

open the CSV and then save as an Excel file.

I gave up on trying to import/export Excel files with R because of hassles like this.

Answer (score 0):

1. In addition to Pete's answer I wouldn't recommend write.csv because it takes or can take minutes to load. I used `fwrite()` (from data.table library) and it did the same thing in about 1-2 secs.
2. The post author asked about large files. I dealt with a table about 2,3 million rows long and write.data (and frwrite) aren't able to write more than about 1 million rows. It just cuts the data away. So instead use `write.table(Data, file="Data.txt")`. You can open it in Excel and split the one column by your delimiter (use argument `sep`) and voila!